# How do I build external SWF in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, compiler-construction, adobe, flash

I have a a module that I want to include in the swf build but I want the swf to be able to use the module (separate swf) externally. How can I build both the application and the module in different swf files? (I know it's something with the compiler, but not quite sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, but here's how to tell FlashBuilder that you want a module to be built:

Right click on the Flash Project, select "Properties", then select "Flex Modules".  Click "Add", and you should be able to browse to your module.